# Why does Chrome choke more often than IE 8 and Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, connection

On my system, Chrome chokes quite more often than IE 8 or Firefox -- it searched for the website for 20 seconds and then said website not found.

I wonder if it could be due to DNS issue or different browsers use different method to connecting to the internet (as Fiddler works for some browser and not for some)?  any method to fix it?  (the ISP here is AT&T u-verse, if it matters).  thanks.

Comment: I've never had such a problem, and I've been various versions for well over 6 months.

Comment: Fiddler works for all browsers, btw.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome has known problems with its DNS pre-fetching, which seem to affect some people and not others (I've never had a problem, plenty of other people have).

You can fix this by disabling DNS pre-fetching. My Digital Life has [instructions](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/17/turn-off-dns-prefetching-in-google-chrome-to-fix-resolving-host-and-cannot-load-page-error/) on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall running? If yes then check whether chrome is permitted to access web or not. Also it may be due to a buggy version of chrome, so upgrading to latest chrome version may fix the problem.

As for the choking problem, i also have that problem sometimes with both chrome and firefox, i've heard it's due improper memory cleanup of chrome(but this problem happens in my older machine with only 512MB RAM). Opera10 usually don't hang that much on that machine.

Comment: Please also see http://superuser.com/questions/65382/does-chrome-use-a-different-dns-server-while-firefox-and-ie-use-a-different-one   that one seems to solve the problem so far