# Windows 8 Chrome DNS issue

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, dns, windows-8.1, timeout

Sometimes when I want to visit random site I get "The server at www.something.here can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed" which looks pretty standard. When I go to "chrome://net-internals/#dns" settings, I get "error: -105 (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)" error.

Suprisingly - when I go to this same exact site using IE it works pretty solid. In my opinion it's default dns timeout span, which is too short (?) and I can't find a way to make it longer but maybe I am missing something?

Windows 8.1 (with all hotfixes)
Chrome stable version (tried beta, nothing changed)
flushing windows DNS (which doesn't help probably because Chrome has it's own DNS cache.

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who are using for you DNS servers?  ISP, google, OpenDNS?  Have you tried switching servers to see if it helps?

Comment: Got 208.67.220.222 and 8.8.4.4 ad Preferred and alternate DNS - can't check it now but as I recall it's opendns + google. Tried to change it but I'm not sure if it helped - problem still exists

Comment: Here's a relevant thread that recommends not mixing DNS services...  http://forums.opendns.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=12307

Comment: I doubt a little that's the case, but I will try it ASAP. Thanks! :)

Comment: I also doubt it, but when in troubleshooting mode, I start with the basics and start with the simplest configuration.  In this case, that would be google OR OpenDNS.

Comment: It took me about 40 minutes to get the error back, but it's here again - I'm using openDNS only. Of course IE or Firefox can handle this same site well

Comment: Have you tried disabling DNS prefetching in Chrome? http://superuser.com/a/65384/98584

Answer (score 1):

You can try flushing Chrome's DNS cache

[image: Flush cache]

If that does not work, consider disabling DNS prefetching.

[image: Disable DNS prefetching]

[More details on Chrome and DNS prefetching](http://hanxue-it.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-disable-dns-prefetching-in.html).

Comment: That option is not present on Version 42.0.2311.90 m (Windows 8.1). Has it moved?