# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in Chrome on a single site

Tags: google-chrome, dns

Our internet connection at the office went down for a bit yesterday, and now Chrome can't find youtube.com. I get the `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error, even though the site loads perfectly fine in other browsers, and I can access other Google sites. I've tried clearing cookies, dumping cache, releasing and renewing ipconfig, everything I can think of, to no avail. What other options are there to try. I'm running Windows 8.1.

Comment: Have you tried turning off DNS prefetching off?

Comment: You said you released/renewed IP address, but have you flushed your DNS cache? `ipconfig /flushdns` and then `ipconfig /registerdns` Make sure Chrome is closed before performing the two commands. Let us know what happens.

Comment: @JSanchez - While I agree they should use those commands. It might be worth pointing out that IE and/or Firefox both work for the user. I wonder if the user has even tried simply restarting the computer.  So its unlikely a system level DNS problem.

Comment: Found this as well: http://superuser.com/questions/65382/does-chrome-use-a-different-dns-server-from-firefox-and-ie-which-use-the-os-defa

Answer (score 10):

A less extreme way to clear the DNS cache (a potential source of this issue) is to go the `chrome://net-internals/#dns` page in Chrome and then click the "Clear host cache" button. This will clear the cache in Chrome and hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: Note that if you click that link in Chrome, the colon is edited out automatically.  Add the colon manually, or copy/paste the link into the search bar.

Comment: I have to do this several times a day. I wish there was some way to permanently fix this.